# Flume got stopped with lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor

Tags: hbase, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

i am trying to sink twitter data into hbase through flume .Flume process got stopped with below information

```
15/08/04 10:11:59 INFO lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Stopping lifecycle supervisor 10
```

This is my flume.conf

```
#source
###############################################################
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HbaseOut

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type=MyTwitterSourceForFlume
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
###############################################################
#chennal
###############################################################
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
###############################################################
# HBase sink config
###############################################################
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.channel =MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.table=Fallowers_table
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.columnFamily=Fallowers_det
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.batchSize = 5000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HbaseOut.serializer = TwitterSplittingSerializer
```

is there any configuration issue with flume.conf? or issue with hbase serializer?

So how do i debug this ?

Comment: You'll need to post more of the log file. The stopping supervisor message happens while Flume is stopping and is caused by something earlier.

Comment: Hi sarge  here is the http://pastebin.com/HgS0236e

Comment: HI Sarge Here i found this piece of information   15/08/05 09:44:50 INFO hbase.AsyncHBaseSink: waiting on callback
15/08/05 09:44:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)